# Question on Email Link sent to waitlisted participant

Tags: civicrm-event, waitlist

We had an event where we turned on the waitlisting feature and emails with the registration link were sent out to the correct participant when his participant status changed to "pending from waitlist".  However, the participant did 2 things which caused some confusion at the CIVICRM side:

1. the participant changed his name when confirming his attendance of the event using the link in the email.  is this allowed and whether this can be disabled ?
2. the participant can re-register again using the same link before it expired and created additional payment record for him but with only the single original participant record.  can a waitlist link be disabled after it is used rather than only expiring after the set period?

it seems that the above 2 points can cause confusion on the participantion/payment tracking for events if users are allowed to change/reuse in the above situations.  Is this observation correct and whether can the said features exist?  Thanks for your advise.

Clement